# Building a float from binary files c

Tags: c, binary

I'm trying to build a float number from a binary file with the following format:

- first 4 bytes represents the number of digits on the left side of "."
  We'll call that X
- Next 4 bytes represents the number of digits on the right side of "."
  We'll call that Y
- Next byte represents the number's sign : "1" => '-', "0" => "+"
- Next X+Y bytes represents the number's digits.

Example:

Data.bin:

4 2 0 2 8 3 9 5 3

The number should be : 2839.53

I've the structure :

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned int digitsBefore;
    unsigned int digitsAfter;
    char sign;
    char *digits;
} Number;
```

Function used to parse and fill the structure :

```
Number *fromBinaryToNumber(FILE *file){
    int counter = 0, size = 0, i = 0;
    size_t bytes_read;

    unsigned int firstIndex, secondIndex;
    char sign;
    char *digits;

    Number *nr = calloc(1, sizeof(Number));

    // reading digits before
    bytes_read = fread(&firstIndex, sizeof(unsigned int), 1, file);
    nr->digitsBefore = firstIndex;

    printf("Bytes read : %zu\n", bytes_read);
    printf("First index %d\n", firstIndex);
    size += firstIndex;

    // reading digits after
    bytes_read = fread(&secondIndex, sizeof(unsigned int), 1, file);
    nr->digitsAfter = secondIndex;

    printf("Bytes read : %zu\n", bytes_read);
    printf("Second index %d\n", secondIndex);
    size += secondIndex;

    // reading sign
    bytes_read = fread(&sign, sizeof(char), 1, file);
    nr->sign = sign;
    printf("Bytes read : %zu\n", bytes_read);
    printf("Sign : %.2X\n", sign);

    //reading digits
    digits = calloc(size, sizeof(unsigned char));
    nr->digits = calloc(size, sizeof(unsigned char));

    printf("Digits : \n");
    bytes_read = fread(digits, size, 1, file);
    for(i = 0 ; i < size; i++){
        printf("%.2X ", digits[i]);
    }

    memcpy(nr->digits, digits, size);
    free(digits);

    return nr;
}
```

For the following data in Data.bin (Hexdumped):

04 00 00 00 02 00 00 00  00 02 08 03 09 05 03

I get the output:

Bytes read : 1
First index : 4
Bytes read : 1
Second Index : 2 
Bytes read : 1
Sign : 00
Digits : 
02 08 03 09 05 03

Function to transform Number strunct in float:

```
double fromNumbertoDouble(Number *number){
    int size = 0;
    char *buff;

    size = number->digitsAfter + number->digitsBefore + 2;
    buff = calloc(size, sizeof(char));
    if (!buff) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error calloc in fromNumberToDouble");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (number->sign == '01') {
        strcat(buff, "-");
    }

    strncat(buff, number->digits, number->digitsBefore);
    strcat(buff, ".");
    strncat(buff, number->digits+number->digitsBefore, number->digitsAfter);

    return atof(buff);
}
```

This always return 0.

When I checked to see what is in the number returned from fromBinaryToNumber, number->digits = "\002\b\003\t\005\003".

I'm aware that atof can't convert something like that into a float.

My question is how can i convert the number->digits into something that would get converted into a float by atof.

Any other idea on how to solve this would also be appreciated.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

For each of the digits, add `'0'`, i.e. the codepoint value for the digit 0. This turns the array into a a sequence of digit characters. Of course, it must also be 0-terminated for `atof()`, which requires a proper string.

You do realize that your format is fantastically awkward, right? A single `float` would use 4 bytes for the entire number, always. If you're going to convert to `float` anyway you're not going to be able to keep the arbitrary precision that your format supports.

Answer (score 0):

First your buffer size is wrong - you've not taken into account the decimal point, sign or the zero-terminator. Also you don't initialise buff - so `strcat` may concatenate anywhere- you should either `calloc`, or `memset` the `buff` to 0 before `strcat`'ing anything to it.

Comment: Edited the size and calloc-ed the buff. Thank you for that.

Comment: Not quite - calloc is defined as calloc(num, size_of_elements)